# UISplitView not receiving rotating event

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller

I am working on an iPad application. Please help me.

I have a normal split view with Root and Detail views.
From the Detail view, I pop up another Child view using presentpresentModalViewController.

I start the app in Portrait mode. Then after the Child view is popped up, I rotated the iPad to Landscape mode. The Child view rotated fine because it received the rotating event. Then I close the Child view (with "Done" button).

BUT the split view DID NOT receive the rotating event so it did not know that it is now in Landscape mode. So, what happens at that time after I close the Child view:
The window is split is half. The left side (Root) is just black. The right side (Detail) is still there (with the popover button still there).

I added codes to get rid of the Popover button in the Detail view in that case. BUT I don't know how to make the Root view appear.
I guess the solution would be.... how to tell the split view that the rotation has been changed, since the rotation was done while it was in the Child view???

Any suggestion is appreciated. I am very new to Objective-C. Thanks so much!!

Summary

1. Start in Portrait mode
2. Click button in Detail view
3. Present modal Child view
4. Rotate to Landscape
5. Close modal Child view
6. Splitview not displayed correctly in now landscape mode (see photo
   please)

https://devforums.apple.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/10556/450-362/Screen+shot+2011-02-23+at+2.58.21+AM.png

Comment: I've searched all over this forum and found this post to be similar to my problem... but I cannot solve the problem with the infos the post provides. My case is like scenario #4 in the OP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795665/problem-after-dismissing-a-modal-view-used-in-conjunction-with-a-uisplitviewcontr

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the UISplitViewController delegate to be the selected Detail view, as this will be the UIViewController that handles the popover once in portrait mode.

So, when assigning the detail view, also assign it as the delegate.  Your detail views will also each need to support the UISplitViewControllerDelegate protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly same issue In my case to dismiss the presented view I don't use animation.if I use animation the issue will gone. Just set animated to YES.

cheers,

Naveen Shan